# ADB0020: Android ABI mismatch. How do I set ABI of target physical device?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a brand new Samsung A10 with Pie on it.

I'm attempting to run the Sample Application provided in MediaPlugin:
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

At first I was getting this error when I tried to build:

> Invalid value 'armeabi' in $(AndroidSupportedAbis). This ABI is no
>   longer supported. Please update your project properties to remove the
>   old value. If the properties page does not show an 'armeabi' checkbox,
>   un-check and re-check one of the other ABIs and save the changes.

Then I did some reasearch and went to Android Properties / Android Options / Advanced and unselected armeabo-v7a.

As I understand it this will remove 32 but support, which I'm fine with.

Now I get this error:

> ADB0020: Android ABI mismatch. You are deploying an app supporting
>   'x86;x86_64;arm64-v8a' ABIs to an incompatible device of ABI
>   'armeabi-v7a;armeabi'. You should either create an emulator matching
>   one of your app's ABIs or add 'armeabi-v7a' to the list of ABIs your
>   app builds for.

I'm targeting a new A10 Samsung phone with Android Pie on it. I can't see where to set the 'device ABI', though why would a new Pie phone be interseted in armeabi-v7a anyway?

Where can I set the 'device ABI' or otherwise fix this?

I can't find anything on Google. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've found this work around which is as worrying as it is bizarre:

- Untick the armeabi-v7a option
- Build
- Re-tick the option
- Build
- Deploy

from
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/146174/vs2019-error-this-abi-is-no-longer-supported

I'd like to understand what's going on here rather than just work around it.

This is only an issue with my A10 physical Samsung phone, in emulators it seems to work fine.

Comment: those settings are dependent on the selected build configuration.  Please be sure you are modifying the ones that correspond to a device deployment, not an emulator deployment.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate a bit please, I'm very new to Xamarin

Comment: Both Debug and Release configurations are the same, just Release has 'Optimize code' checked. Both have Any CPU as platform target. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 41):

I got this error before. You could untick all the `supported architectures` to tick all of them like below. Delete the obj and bin folder of project to clean and rebuild. Most of times, it works.

[image]

Different Android devices use different CPUs, which in turn support different instruction sets. Each combination of CPU and instruction set has its own Application Binary Interface (ABI).

For more support of Android ABIs, you could refer to the Android ABIs guides.
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

Comment: Thanks. So this is a bug, to be clear? Also you're saying untick them, delete obj and bin, then retick them? I found unticking v7a building then reticking is a work around (see updated question)

Comment: Yes, it is the same way. Untick and then retick like what I do in the .gif screenshot. Somethimes, VS do not accept the sets with the device well. Do something to make the VS check it would be helpful. I think this is not a bug,  because it would be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. How can it not be a bug?! Surely this isn't by design?

Comment: This maybe a potential issue, you could report it on GitHub.https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Unticking v7a option worked. Ticking it back doesn't work.

Comment: Still exists in VS 2022. Came here to find the solution only to find I've already found and upvoted this answer before.  jfc

Answer (score 19):

To fix this issue on a Xamarin.Forms Android application, Right click on your android project and then select **Properties > Android Options > Advanced**.

You will see a dropdown for supported architectures. Select **x84 & x86_64**.

The app should now build and run on the emulator.

Answer (score 9):

go to your project folder and edit yourproject.csproj

and remove starting  `<AndroidSupportedAbis>`  line completely.

add:

```
<AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;x86_64;arm64-v8a;x86</AndroidSupportedAbis>
```

save and debug. (changes accept on visual studio)

Enjoy.

Do not setup retry abis on xamarin.

Comment: I started seeing this error appear after starting to Archive my projects for distribution. @UmutAvci, your suggestion worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to check and uncheck using the VS 2019 GUI (Windows) and it didn't work for me at all. In the end, I unloaded the Android project and added the line (single line and not multiple) and that did it for me :)

Comment: This answer is worth its weight in gold. I only lost 3 hours before finding this. Thank God for Stack Overflow and contributors like @Umut.

Answer (score 4):

I changed to **Debug mode** from *Release mode* after signing a release.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac:

Android Project -> <kbd>Option</kbd> -> <kbd>Android Build</kbd> -> <kbd>Advanced</kbd>. Then tick all.

Click Option from Solution Explorer for Android:

[image: Click Option from Solution Explorer for Android]

Click Android Build then Advanced:
[image: Click Android Build then Advanced]