# Dotnet Maui while install application on device

Tags: .net, maui

ADB0020: Mono.AndroidTools.IncompatibleCpuAbiExceptiopn: The package does not support the CPU architecture of this device.

My device detail

Device : Lg Q6

Api : - 27

Kernel Version : 3.18.71

Comment: Divyesh patel : Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the built Android APK did not contain a matching Android architecture for the emulator or device it was deployed to.

Follow the steps below to change the supported architectures.
Android Properties> Android Options> Advanced> Change the supported architectures.
[image]

You could untick all the supported architectures to tick all of them like the gif in the thread I did before.
[ADB0020: Android ABI mismatch. How do I set ABI of target physical device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624392/adb0020-android-abi-mismatch-how-do-i-set-abi-of-target-physical-device/58636012#58636012)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the built Android APK didn't contain a matching Android architecture for the emulator or device.

For MAUI it's can mean that emulator is not up to date.

Try these steps:

1. Use [maui-check](https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check) tool to auto-resolve issues
2. Recreate emulator
3. Run app again